# How to convert SQL data on webpage so any data that is a URL becomes a hyperlink?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, hyperlink

I have a website that has a table. The table displays data from MySQL. There are multiple columns in the table. One of the columns is a URL column.

**Issue**

- Currently the table displays the full URL and its not clickable.

**Questions:**

- How do I make the text clickable?
- Should I be using Javascript to solve this? or PHP?

**Objectives**

- Check the column with the class ID "urlColumn" to see if...

  - Cell is `blank`

    - Leave cell blank
  - Cell begins with `<a href`

    - Do nothing, URL is already a hyperlink
  - Cell is not blank, and does not have `<a href`

    - Convert this URL to a hyperlink.

**Current Solution**
Its not working. It just leaves everything blank, or converts everything in that column to a hyperlink (even if there is no URL found)

```
setInterval(() => { 
   let urlColumn = document.getElementsByClassName('urlColumn');
   for (let i = 0; i < urlColumn.length; i++) {

      //Checks to see if the URL cell is blank.
      if (urlColumn[i].innerHTML = '') {
         //Do nothing.

      //Checks to see if the URL is already hyperlinked.
      } else if (urlColumn[i].innerHTML = '<a href*') {
         //Do nothing. URL already converted to hyperlink.

      //Cell is not blank, and has not yet been converted to hyperlink.
      } else {

         //Stores the current value of the cell (the URL)
         var urlColumnInner = document.getElementsByClassName('urlColumn')[i];

         //Adds <a href> tag and the URL value to create the hyperlink.
         urlColumnInner = '<a href="' + urlColumnInner + '">OPEN</a>';            
      }
   }
}, 5000);
```

Comment: Don't forget you need to use `==` to compare variables, not `=` as you have in here. A single `=` is used to assign a value to a variable. Your first `if` condition assigns a blank to your `urlColumn[i].innerHTML`, checks that it worked (which it would) so does nothing.

Comment: It's difficult to answer this question without having Idea on how table looks like and what is its actual contents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks droopsnoot for catching my error with the single `=`.

I have made some additional modifications, and the code is working perfectly.

You can view the JSFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/arhzqy0m/1/)

**HTML**

```
<html>
<body>
<p>This table contains data pulled from a SQL database. The URL's are in plan text, and are not clickable. The javascript will scan through the URL column, and make the URLs into clickable hyperlinks every 5 seconds.</p>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th> 
    <th>URL</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td class="urlColumn">https://1example.com</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td class="urlColumn"><a href="https://2example.com">OPEN</a></td>
  </tr>
      <td>Bob</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td class="urlColumn">https://3example.com</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
    <td class="urlColumn"></td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

**Javascript**

```
//Runs every 5 seconds.
setInterval(() => {
 
  //Gets the DOM element with class id urlColumn.
   var urlColumn = document.getElementsByClassName('urlColumn');
  
  //Loops through every element with the class id urlColumn.
   for (var i = 0; i < urlColumn.length; i++) {

      //Checks every cell with the class id urlColumn, and if a blank one is found, do nothing.
      if (urlColumn[i].innerHTML.length == 0) {

      //Checks every cell with the class id urlColumn, and if its already hyperlinked do nothing.
      } else if (urlColumn[i].innerHTML.indexOf('<a href') != -1) {

      //If the first 2 ifs are not true, we know the cell with class id urlColumn is not blank, and is not hyperlinked. 
      } else {
        //Get the non hyperlink URL, and add hyperlink tags.
         urlColumn[i].innerHTML = '<a href="' + urlColumn[i].innerHTML + '"' + 'target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">OPEN</a>'; 
      }
   }
  //Run this function every 5 seconds.
}, 5000);
```